# Add .ics from URL to Google calendar only shows 'busy'

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am developing a web application which dynamically distributes several .ics files on the web space. So now I am trying to observe those .ics files from mail clients like macOS calendar app, Outlook or Google calendar. Everything works simply perfect with all except Google calendar:

If I am trying to import the calendar from an URL ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHZa9.png)) I just get displayed 'busy' as subject for each event ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2hRa.png)). This is a weird problem because it works like charm in all other apps. It also works fine if I download the current .ics file and import it statically. (So this can **not** be only an .ics content problem)

Well, I already checked out several related issues/questions (see bottom) but none provided a capable/correct solution.

Interesting to mention (the last related question brought me to this):

It **works** if I rearrange the paths and names to the following:

```
https://myurl.net/calendar.ics
```

It does **not work** if I use some of the following patterns:

```
https://myurl.net/ccalendar.ics
https://myurl.net/foo/calendar.ics
```

I also posted this problem in Googles calendar forums but the recommended to post something here.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Regards

Related:

- [my web ical url does not work in google calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327304/my-web-ical-url-does-not-work-in-google-calendar)
- [iCalendar events imported in Google Calendar are empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38329950/icalendar-events-imported-in-google-calendar-are-empty)
- [Events from iCal Feed URL Display as "Busy" in Google Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8052659/events-from-ical-feed-url-display-as-busy-in-google-calendar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experiments I decided to use an [ICS validator](https://icalendar.org/validator.html) found on google. It displayed that the MIME-Type of the URLs result may be misconfigured (`text/plain` should be `text/calendar`). 
I already noticed this while accessing URLs like `https://myurl.net/foo/bar.ics` and seeing plain .ics file content instead of downloading this file. This seems to depend on the browser, some browsers auto interpret this type correctly but Google seems to do not.

However: There's a configuration file named **web.xml** in my applications WEB-INF. I defined the MIME-Type manually for files ending with *.ics:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
    ...     
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>ics</extension>
        <mime-type>text/calendar</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Now even Google Calendar recognizes the whole calendar content independent from the URL it was distributed from.

**EDIT:**

Okay after intense testing there orruced no more problems with any calendar so this seems to be the solution in my case. Outlook, macOS calendar app and Mozilla Thunderbird seem to *guess* the MIME-Type correctly, Google does not.

Answer (score 0):

Try the provided solution in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8053420):

> The calendar's URL that I provided GCal did not end in a filename (I
>   use a PHP framework with URL rewriting). I updated the URL, appending
>   "/calendar.ics" to it and subscribed to the URL in GCal, and now all
>   events seem to display fine, showing all details.

Comment: Thanks, but as you can see in my question I already tried out this pattern.
I need to rename the file or at least put it in any directory path. But none of this works.